# Neo4j - query on two different graphs ( equivalent to SQl joins on tables from different db's)

Tags: join, neo4j, cypher

Till now, I queried neo4j graph db in two ways,

1. Using server, where I need to select the data base, starting the
   server, and querying via web page.
2. Using Java, In which, selecting the database path, creating the database object and executing the query.

Now, I am shifting from MySQL to Neo4j, where I have to replicate those databases and has to perform join queries.

My initial thought to do is, replicating every database in MySQL as a graph db in Neo4j. But, I don't have any clue on **querying on two different graph's** at a time.

*Putting my question straightly:*

**`How to perform join query on two different graphs in neo4j?`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j doesn't really have a concept of different graphs.  Each Neo4j database is all one big graph.  You can store one set of nodes with a certain set of labels along side another set of nodes with another set of labels.  Those two groups could be unconnected or connected in a few places and they could be thought of as different graphs, but there's nothing special to separate them.

If you want to have different Neo4j databases, you need to have different databases directories (`graph.db`).  In server mode those would be handled by different server installations with different sets of ports.  In Java they can simply be in different directories.  There is no way to run a "join" between two datasets in either case without loading your data into memory and doing whatever you like to have one dataset.